# How can i update 1 object in array?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is how my data appears on html :

[image]

`page.html`

```
<ul id="elements">
          <li *ngFor="let elem of fetchdata" (click)="log(elem)">
              {{elem.title}} {{elem.description}}
          </li>
      </ul>
```

`page.ts` Here i get data from localstorage.

**What I want is - when I click on my text, the `title` element of the clicked object of array should get updated,**
    `//ARRAY STRUCTURE JUST FOR YOUR NEED
    //[{title:"saurabh" , description:"dd" , tagline:"tt", date:"dd"}];`

```
this.fetchdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('education'));

  log(elem,index) { 
    console.log(elem); 
    console.log(index);

//WHEN I CLICK, I WANT THE TITLE TO BE UPDATED TO "CLICKED", REST ALL PROPERTIES TO REMAIN SAME

//ARRAY STRUCTURE JUST FOR YOUR NEED
//[{title:"saurabh" , description:"dd" , tagline:"tt", date:"dd"}];

    localStorage.setItem("education",JSON.stringify(this.fetchdata));
  }
```

Comment: Very unclear. Your objects don't have any name. They have a title, a description, a tagline and a date. But you want to update their name. So, what do you actually mean? And what have you tried?

Comment: i want to update the name in my object, not the name of the object

Comment: i am so sorry, i mean `title`

Comment: So, instead, of `console.log(elem)`, you want `elem.title = 'CLICKED';`. Right? What's the difficulty?

Comment: YEP and console.log should show everything else to be same in localstorage

Comment: So, you have your answer. Add `elem.title = 'CLICKED';`, and then print elem to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You want to access title of the object elem, simply

```
log(elem,index) { 
    console.log(elem.title); 
}
```